# Is it possible to change the name of a minted native asset?

Tags: native-assets

Native assets are defined by a fingerprint. This is decoupled from the name, so far as I know. Is it possible to modify the name of the asset after minting it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any Native asset is uniquely identified by policy id + asset name.

- Policy id is the hash of minting policy script, which does not contain asset name.
- Asset name is included in the minting transaction metadata.
  Therefore multiple assets can have the same policy id.

However, since the assert's name is included in the transaction metadata, it can not be changed.